# Moving from one catch to another try catch block

Tags: java

I have multiple try catch blocks. I want to make my program so that if something isn't found in the first block, the catch of that block will continue it to the other set of try catch.
I did some research but wasn't able to come up with a solution.

```
try{
    Something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Move to next set of try catch
    }
```

This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to nest the try-catch blocks like this?

Comment: I have different elements which are doing the exact same thing but of different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587952/moving-from-one-catch-to-another-try-catch-block#comment110683152_62587988):

> I have 4 Elements for which I need to create try catch blocks, i.e. 4 try catch blocks

To try 4 different blocks of code, you'd write it like this:

```java
try {
    // Attempt 1
} catch (Exception e1) {
    try {
        // Attempt 2
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        try {
            // Attempt 3
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            try {
                // Attempt 4
            } catch (Exception e4) {
                RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException("All attempts failed", e1);
                e.addSuppressed(e2);
                e.addSuppressed(e3);
                e.addSuppressed(e4);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add finally block below the try catch , finally will run even if some error found in try block . You can look on below code snippet and can replace your code where method1 will have all the code that you want to run in first block and so on

```
 try {
        method1();
    }finally {
        try {
            method2();
        }finally {
            try {
                method3();
            }finally {
                try {
                    method4();
                }finally {

                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have 4 Elements for which I need to create try catch blocks, i.e. 4 try catch blocks

Comment: If you have 4 blocks and if that will be constant then you need to manage different try catch for each block

Comment: Everything is happening inside the doInBackground method. All the 4 elements are part of it. So same block.

Comment: Please check the updated answer , you need to move block1 code in method1, block2 code in method2 and so on. You can use catch block also above finally block to print exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216692/discussion-between-avinash-tiwari-and-kaneki).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void tryBlock() {
    try {
        // Enter Your Code;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" exception :: " + e);
        tryBlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably something like this is the answer, but some comments in addition to the code would be nice. Probably tryBlock needs some parameters as the second call is using "different classes".

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple try with multiple catch. Like :

```
try{
    something;
}catch(exception){
    Exception2;
}
catch(exception2){
    Exception2;
}


Or you can use nested try-catch like:

try{
  statement
  try{
      statement
      try{
          something
      }catch(exception1){
          Exception
      }
    }catch(exception2){
         Exception2
    }
  }catch(Exception3){
       Exception3
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kaneki If you want to use nested try-catch block execution in such a way that if operation is not perform inside try block then operation would be in catch block

For this you have to test for the condition whether you want to forward in catch block or not.

**Note : To forward from *Try block* to  *Catch block* you have to throw Exception from *Try block* which must be catched by *Catch block*.**

This code may help you as per your requirement:

```
public void nestedTryCatch(){
        boolean wantTogoForNext = false;
        try{
            wantTogoForNext = false;
            doSomthing("Attempt-I");
            wantTogoForNext = true;
            if(wantTogoForNext)
                throw new Exception("1");
        }catch(Exception e1){
            try{
                wantTogoForNext = false;
                doSomthing("Attempt-2");
                wantTogoForNext = true;
                if(wantTogoForNext)
                    throw new Exception("2");
            }catch(Exception e2){
                try{
                    wantTogoForNext = false;
                    doSomthing("Attempt-3");
                    wantTogoForNext = true;
                    if(wantTogoForNext)
                        throw new Exception("3");
                }catch(Exception e3){
                    try{
                        wantTogoForNext = false;
                        doSomthing("Attempt-4");
                        wantTogoForNext = true;
                        if(wantTogoForNext)
                            throw new Exception("4");
                    }catch(Exception e4){
                        
                        try{
                            wantTogoForNext = false;
                            doSomthing("Attempt-5");
                            wantTogoForNext = true;
                            if(wantTogoForNext)
                                throw new Exception("5");
                        }catch(Exception e5){               
                            
                            doSomthing("Attempt-Last");
                            
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



public void doSomthing(String attempt){
        System.out.println(attempt);
    }
```